# Custom gemset RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I want to create my own gemset for my application.
Gems installed and using from local dir(app/vendor/bundle/...)

When I try to execute:

```
rvm gemset create myapp
```

it's creating new gemset.

But how I can create new gemset based on already installed gems?

---

Update: @marat

Almost. But in your example you already had created gemset @rails4 before, right? And you can copy it for another version on ruby.

In my case I haven't installed gems in system, respectively I haven't gemset and can't copy it.
Point is - gems are not placed on host, everything stored in deb package(in directory with app) which created by jenkins. And I need to create gemset which will be linked to app/vendor/bundle/...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your current gemset.

```
$ rvm gemset copy 2.1.1@rails4 2.1.2@rails4
```

https://rvm.io/gemsets/copying

**UPDATE**

Create new gemset

```
rvm gemset create jenkins_gems
```

Delete `gems` folder from that created gemset folder

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@jenkins_gems/gems
```

Then make symlink `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@jenkins_gems/gems` pointing to your gems folder `app/vendor/bundle`

```
ln -s app/vendor/bundle ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@jenkins_gems/gems
```

Caveat: your ruby version may be different so change you path respectively.